# cv2 & list operation lead to out of memory error

Tags: python, image, list, opencv, memory

```
rotated_images = []
for i in range(0, rotation_matrices.shape[0]):
    rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(image, rotation_matrices[i,:,:], (bound_w[i], bound_h[i]))
    rotated_images.append(rotated_image)
```

I have a lot of rotated images by applying warpAffine, which I want to append to the list of rotated_images. But the kernel of my jupyter notebook always dies, it should be due to the cv2::out of memory error. What can I do here instead? I though to stack the rotated images to a numpy array, but the problem is the different size of the warpAffine output..

Comment: What do you want to do with those images? You can save those images to your disk or if you want to train any ML model on them then you can process them in batches.

Comment: Don't use so much memory then. Why do you need to keep so many images in memory at once?

Comment: I need them for further pre-processing steps, in order to train a model later.. If this would be the last step of pre-processing, it would be good idea to train the model by feeding data in batches. But is there another way to handle it here?